# swift 5 Unable to read text file from icloud data storage

Tags: ios, swift, icloud

I am using Swift 5 and Xcode 13.2 for building an iOS app.

I am not able to read a text file from iCloud. I did following preparing:

In the iCloud file I defined some folders und uploaded a text file with content:

> Hello iCloud!

These folders and files are visible in Finder's iCloud file's directory. In terminal the folders and files are visible too.

With the following code I did some tests.

```
    // Step 1: Check iCloud document path
    let docPath = FileManager.default.url(forUbiquityContainerIdentifier: nil)?.appendingPathComponent("Documents")
    print("\(docPath!)\n")
    -> file:///Users/Heinz/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/414...35/data/Library/Mobile%20Documents/iCloud~dxyz/Documents/

    // Step 2: Get directories at document path
    do {
        let contents = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(atPath: docPath!.path)
        print("\(contents)\n")
    } catch { }
    -> ["myDir01", "MyDir02", ".Trash"]
    
    // Step 3: Get deep search from document path
    do {
        let contents = try FileManager.default.subpathsOfDirectory(atPath: docPath!.path)
        print("\(contents)\n")
    } catch { }
   ->["MyDir01", "MyDir02", , "MyDir02/MyDir03, "MyDir02/MyDir03/.Testdatei.txt.icloud", ".Trash"]
    
    // Step 4: Check existence of Testdatei.txt
    var filePath = docPath?.appendingPathComponent("MyDir02/MyDir03/Testdatei.txt")
    var fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath!.path, isDirectory: nil)
    print("filePath: \(filePath!)\n")
    print("File exists: \(fileExists)\n")
    -> File Testdatei.txt exists: false
    
    // Step 5: Check existence of .Textdatai.txt.icloud
    filePath = docPath?.appendingPathComponent("MyDir02/MyDir03/.Testdatei.txt.icloud")
    print("filePath: \(filePath!)\n")
    fileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filePath!.path, isDirectory: nil)
    print("File exists: \(fileExists)\n")
    -> File .Testdatei.txt.icloud exists: true
    
    // Step 6: Cheack readability of .Textdatai.txt.icloud
    let isReadable = FileManager.default.isReadableFile(atPath: filePath!.path)
    print("File is readable: \(isReadable)\n")
    -> File .Testdatei.txt.icloud is readable: true
    
    // Step 7. Get content of .Textdatai.txt.icloud
    let fileContent = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: filePath!.path)
    let dataString = String(decoding: fileContent!, as: UTF8.self)
    print("File content: \(dataString)\n")
    -> File .Testdatei.txt.icloud content:
```

> bplist00�\NSURLNameKey_NSURLFileSizeKey_NSURLFileResourceTypeKey]Testdatei.txt
> _NSURLFileResourceTypeRegular/JXZy

Step 1: The iCloud Document's path seems to be ok.

Step 2: The directories are ok too.

Step 3: The directory strcture is ok. However, the file name is modified by a leading dot and the trailing .icloud.

Step 4: The file with the original name "TestDatei.txt" doesn't exist.

Step 5: The file with the modified name ".Testdatei.txt.icloud" exists.

Step 6: The file with modified name is readable.

Step 7: Reading the file with modified name and converting data to String results in something which seems to be some metadata, but not the expected file content, which is "Hello iCloud!"

What is going wrong?